# Quaternions just a sum of vector products?

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

I noticed that I can get a quaternion by adding the scalar value of a dot product between two vectors to the cross product of the same two vectors. Is that just pure coincidence, or is that how it was "meant" to be?

Comment: Can you give examples?  I think thus is right but need some examples to analyze.

Comment: This isn't quite accurate; the scalar term in a product of two quaternions is the product of the scalar terms _minus_ the dot product of the 'imaginary' portions of the two quaternions. But no, it's certainly not coincidence. You might want to see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984438/is-there-a-relationship-between-the-cross-product-and-quaternion-multiplication?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752070/motivation-for-construction-of-cross-product-quaternions?noredirect=1&lq=1 and a couple of other questions on this site...

Comment: By "get a quaternion", perhaps you mean [the scalar-vector split multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Algebraic_properties)$$(p_s+\vec{p}_v)(q_s+\vec{q}_v)=(p_sq_s-\vec{p}_v\cdot\vec{q}_v)+(p_s\vec{q}_v+q_s\vec{p}_v+\vec{p}_v\times\vec{q}_v).$$(I've edited my comment to use Wikipedia's notation, so you can find their discussion more easily. They don't put arrows over the vectors. @Andrei's reference below is to the original version of my comment, which had $p_s=a,\,q_s=b$.)

Comment: In @J.G. 's comment, if $a=b=0$, you get a scalar product and a vector product